# Python argparse to a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to figure out argparse for my adventure game.
This is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adventure')
parser.add_argument('--cheat','-c', action='store_true', help='cheat')
parser.add_argument('--info','-i', action='store_true', help='Information' )
parser.add_argument('--version','-v', action='store_true', help='Version' )
parser.add_argument('--about', '-a', action='store_true', help='About' )

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.cheat or args.c:
    print("Cheat")
    sys.exit()
elif args.info or args.i:
    print("Information")
    sys.exit()
elif args.version or args.v:
    print("Version")
    sys.exit()
elif args.about or args.a:
    print("About")
    sys.exit()
else:
    #Game code#
```

But I'm getting an error when I have all these arguments. It worked fine when I only had cheat to begin with but when I added all the others, it messed up. Either I dont really know what i'm doing or I cant see whats wrong...

Here is my error:

```
$ python3 adventure.py --info
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adventure.py", line 12, in <module>
  if args.cheat or args.c:
      AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'c'
```

The reason I have it like this is because I want to type in this in terminal without starting the game, so if you just type python3 adventure.py the game will start. But I cant even do that now :P.
Only python3 adventure.py -c and python3 adventure --cheat works.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages is pretty clear: `'Namespace' object has no attribute 'c'`.

`argparse` library automatically determines the name of the attribute to store the value of the command line option [in the following way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest):

> For optional argument actions, the value of `dest` is normally inferred from the option strings. `ArgumentParser` generates the value of `dest` by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--` string. If no long option strings were supplied, `dest` will be derived from the first short option string by stripping the initial `-` character.

Since you have both long and short names for your option, the long name is used. In other words, replace `if args.cheat or args.c:` with `if args.cheat:`.